# Best way of executing js function located in parent page from custom element

Tags: aurelia

Aurelia: I have a custom element that should execute a function that located in the parent page. the custom element doesn't "know" what function it should execute - it depends on the parent page, and currently I send the name of the function as an attribute to the custom element (the attribute - on-focus-out-action-name):

```
<form-input field-name="firstName" title="First Name" on-focus-out-action-name ="validateInput()" />
```

I manage to run the function when it has no params, but when I want to send params (simple string type which is also sent as attribute) - no success

Is there a better way to do it ? 
The best way was if I could pass the function as an object (Dependency Injection ?)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `call` binding command for this. The way to pass parameters to a function when using the `call` bind is a bit wonky, but once you understand it, it's easy.

In the custom element, you will pass an object to the bound function. Each property of this function will be matched to the named parameters in the binding. Let's look at it in action. In the page VM, I'll have a function:

```
 pageFunction(paramOne, paramtwo) {
   //.. stuff happens
 }
```

This function will be called by a custom element. So in the page view, we will write the binding like this:

```
 <my-element some-func.call="pageFunction(paramOne, paramTwo)"></my-element>
```

Inside `my-element`'s VM, we can call the bound function, and pass the parameters to it like this:

```
this.someFunc({paramOne: this.someProp, paramTwo: this.otherProp});
```

I've created a runnable gist example here: https://gist.run/?id=864edc684eb107cdd71c58785b14d2f9

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using a CustomEvent for this, this makes it clear in the template what is going on.

In your component you dispatch the event like this - the "details" can be any object/data you want:

```
let event = new CustomEvent('on-focus-out-action-name', { 
        detail: <some-data-you-want-to-send>,
        bubbles: true
    });
this.element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

You'll also need to inject the element in the constructor (you'll also need to use autoinject or inject Element manually)

```
constructor(private element: Element) {}
```

Your parent template would then look something like this:

```
<form-input field-name="firstName" 
  title="First Name" 
  on-focus-out-action-name.delegate="validateInput($event)" />
```

And in your parent component, you use the data you sent like this:

```
validateInput(event) {
    let data = event.detail;
    // do stuff
}
```

Check out this blog post for more details https://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/08/aurelia-custom-elements-custom-callback-events-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it in Aurelia: This is the custom element with the foucusout.trigger which calls to the focusoutAction in the appropriate timing:

```
<template>
 <label>
     ${title} - ${fieldName}<input title.bind="title" 
     focusout.trigger="focusoutAction()" focusin.trigger="focusInAction()" 
     class="${cssClass}" />
  </label>
</template>
```

This is the usage of the custom element in the parent view with the focusout.call attribute:

```
<form-input field-name="firstName" title="First Name" 
  place-holder="Enter first name" 
  on-focusout.call="validateInput(nameOfElement)" />
```

And this is the relevant code in the view model of the custom control:

```
@bindable onFocusout;

focusoutAction() {
  var args =
  {
     nameOfElement: this.fieldName
  };
  this.onFocusout(args);
}
```